# How does electrical energy in parallel work out?how does less energy travel through more resistance,and lose the electrical energy which it not had?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, potential-energy, voltage, electrical-engineering

[image: assume the battery is of 12 volts and all the 3 resistors are of 36 ohms]

Before asking my question,I want to talk about certain points
1.Lets suppose there is a battery of 12 volts,this means that the potential difference between the negative and positive terminal of the battery is 12V,and that every 1 coulomb of charge gets 12 joules of energy when it is in the negative terminal and spends it in travelling from the negative terminal to the positive terminal through the wire,and in the resistance as well
2.In Parallel circuit,the voltage across all the resistors is the same as the voltage of battery,let's suppose 12 volts,and the current gets divided at point 2,3,4,5,6

Now, according to maths,the equivalent resistance of the 3 resistors is 12 resistance,then,the current flowing should be 1 Ampere,since,V=IR,and voltage is also 12 volts and total resistance is also 12 volts,then the current flowing through each resistor will be 0.3 Ampere,now,the battery is going to give 12 joules of charge to every coulomb,but,the current through the individual resistors is 0.3 Coulomb per second,this means that the electrical energy they will have will be only 4 joules, but the voltage of resistance is 12 volts, meaning 1C of charge will lose 12 joules of energy

My final question is,WILL THE 0.33 COULOMB OF CHARGE GIVE ONLY 4 JOULES OF ENERGY TO THE RESISTOR WHEN IT WAS SUPPOSE TO GIVE 12 JOULES OF ENERGY(BECAUSE VOLTAGE OF ANY INDIVIDUAL RESISTOR IS 12 V) BECAUSE THE CHARGE ITSELF DID NOT HAVE 12 JOULES OF ENERGY(BECAUSE IT WAS ONLY O.33 COULOMBS OF CHARGE) ,IF IT WOULD HAVE HAD MORE ENERGY,THEN IT WOULD HAVE GIVEN MORE ENERGY, RIGHT(IF MORE CHARGE WOULD HAVE PASSED,THEN MORE ENERGY WOULD HAVE BEEN GIVEN TO THE RESISTOR, RIGHT?this might sound silly and obvious,but is this true?

I am in 10th grade and 15 years old,so, please avoid using concepts not thought to average 10th grade students,thanks!

Comment: This site uses MathJax to format Maths stuff. For example to get the fraction $\frac{1}{3}$ you type \frac{1}{3} with a dollar sign before and after. This is clearer for this question than writing $0.3$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since the current is $1$ Ampere, in $1$ second there will be $1$ Coulomb of charge flowing through the battery, picking up $12$ Joules of energy from the battery. This energy gets distributed to the three resistors. Each resistor carries a third of the current, ie $\frac{1}{3}$ Ampere, so it passes $\frac{1}{3}$ Coulomb during this second, so it  dissipates $\frac{1}{3}\times12=4$ Joules of this energy. The total for the three resistors together is $12$ Joules dissipated (as heat), the same as the energy provided by the battery.

If you look at each resistor separately, $1$ coulomb passing through it will dissipate 12 Joules of energy. Ohm's Law $V=IR$ tells us the current is given by $12=I\times36$, so $I=\frac{1}{3}$Ampere in each resistor, leading to the same answer as before.

Comment: So,the coulomb of charge having 4 joules of energy will lose only 4 joules when it was supposed to lose 12 joules of energy per coulomb,if it would have that much energy in it?right?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah,so I basically mean to ask a obvious thing,the 1/3 coulomb of charge having 4 joules of energy will only be able to give 4 joules of energy to the resistor, because it doesn't have more,if it would have more,then it would have given more, right?

Comment: Yes; it has to lose all its energy by the time it gets back to the battery.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir/mam

Comment: On this site, if you like an answer you can upvote it, rewarding the answerer by giving them reputation points. When you have asked a question you can accept an answer, which also gives points to the answerer. On the other hand if you think an answer is wrong you can downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

A $12 \,\rm V$ battery is connected to a complete circuit.

An electrochemical reaction does $12 \,\rm J$ of work in moving  $+1\,\rm C$ of charge through the battery from node $8$ to node $1$.
When $+1\,\rm C$ of charged is moved from node $1$ to node $8$ via the resistors, $12\,\rm J$ of heat is dissipated in the resistors.

So there is a balanced energy equation.

$12 \,\rm J$ of chemical energy is converted to electrical energy within the battery and $12 \,\rm J$ of electrical energy is converted to heat within the resistors.

If the resistors each have the same resistance then the $12 \,\rm J$ of electrical energy is converted to $4\,\rm J$ of heat within each of the resistors.

In this case because the current through the battery is $1\,\rm A = 1\,C\,s^{-1}$ the balanced energy equation in terms of power is;

the rate of conversion of  chemical energy to electrical energy within the battery is $12 \,\rm W$ and this is equal to the rate of conversion of electrical energy to heat within the resistors,$12 \,\rm W$, with each resistor converting electrical energy into heat at a rate of  $4\,\rm W$.

Comment: Yeah,so I was just asking a obvious and silly question,WILL THE 0.33 COULOMB OF CHARGE GIVE ONLY 4 JOULES OF ENERGY TO THE RESISTOR WHEN IT WAS SUPPOSE TO GIVE 12 JOULES OF ENERGY(BECAUSE VOLTAGE OF ANY INDIVIDUAL RESISTOR IS 12 V) BECAUSE THE CHARGE ITSELF DID NOT HAVE 12 JOULES OF ENERGY(BECAUSE IT WAS ONLY O.33 COULOMBS OF CHARGE) ,IF IT WOULD HAVE HAD MORE ENERGY,THEN IT WOULD HAVE GIVEN MORE ENERGY, RIGHT(IF MORE CHARGE WOULD HAVE PASSED,THEN MORE ENERGY WOULD HAVE BEEN GIVEN TO THE RESISTOR, RIGHT?